# Appease mypy where None is type hinted and other operands are used

Tags: python, mypy, nonetype

I have 2 pieces of code where default values could be None, but the None values are caught before the operation (>) or iteration of a list. Mypy is still producing an error message despite the fact that I can't see how None could get through in either case.

```
def plot_columns(df: pd.DataFrame, columns: list[str] | None = None):
    if not columns:
        columns = df.columns

    for col in columns:
        plt.plot(df[col])
```

```
def function_2(tup: tuple[float | int | None, float | int | None]) -> bool:
    assert len(tup) == 2

    if all(tup):  # Also tried: if tup.count(None) == 0
        return tup[0] > tup[1]

    return False
```

In both cases mypy throws errors

first: Item "None" of "Optional[List[str]]" has no attribute "__iter__" (not iterable)  [union-attr]

second (multiple similar errors): Unsupported operand types for > ("float" and "None")  [operator]

Is there a better way to write these or a more pythonic way to do it? Or should I just ignore mypy on this one?

***Edit***: Appeased the first one by making it an empty list.

Comment: I know lots of Python code snippets out in the wild likes to test falseyness by simultaneously handling booleans, `None`, containers of length 0, integers of value 0, and so on, but seriously *don’t* do this. It’s difficult to read and results in buggy code. `function_2` results in `False` if you pass in `(3, 0)` - is that really what you want?

Comment: try`if columns is not None:` for the first one, note, I don't think mypy's type narrowing will be able to handle the second case

Comment: For the second case, you may want to [use a user-defined type guard](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type_narrowing.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: @dROOOze you're right, I hadn't factored that in, although in my specific case I actually do want that behaviour. It is still better to be more explicit about the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, `pandas` itself doesn't seem to have typed `df.columns` so that you can tell statically that the value is not `None`. Try

```
def plot_columns(df: pd.DataFrame, columns: list[str] | None = None):
    if not columns:
        columns = cast(list[str], df.columns)
    ...
```

For the second one, `all(tup)` doesn't seem to be on `mypy`'s list of recognized forms for type narrowing. (Or, type narrowing lets you narrow the type of `tup` itself, not the elements of `tup`.) Be more explicit:

```
def function_2(tup: tuple[float | int | None, float | int | None]) -> bool:
    
    assert len(tup) == 2

    a, b = tup

    if a is None or b is None:
        return False

    returnn a > b
```